# rewriting issue with $_GET

Tags: php, asp.net, .htaccess

i have something like

```
RewriteRule ^home$ ?get=main
```

inside my `.htaccess` to redirect any url calls from `mysite.com/index?get=main` to `mysite.com/home`

but when i use any quotation marks like `'` and `"` after that url it dosen't behave correctly and dosen't access the file in question, for example if i type

`mysite.com/home'` or `mysite.com/home"` (notice the quotations) it redirects off to another page and dosen't access the file at all which should be `mysite.com/index?get=main` and when i use `mysite.com/index?get=main'` or `mysite.com/index?get=main"` it accesses those files then.

i want it to either access the `mysite.com/index?get=main` file from `mysite.com/index?get=main"` or give a 404 error page, right now it's doing neither, what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The rewrite rule is looking for an explicit value of `home` to match to the ?get=main.

Try

```
RewriteRule ^home ?get=main
```